# Grails 3 asset-pipeline / coffee-asset pipeline

Tags: grails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

I am using asset-pipeline to manage my front end resources for my Grails 3.0 application. However it seems that source-maps for CoffeeScript files are not created. Is there any way to enable this?

My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.6.2'
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:coffee-asset-pipeline:2.6.2'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "0.1"
group "grails2"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    enableSourceMaps = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:coffee-asset-pipeline:2.6.2'



    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

This is my application.coffee

```
#= require test
#= require_tree .
#= require_self

console.log "This is my manifest"
$ ->
    $("#spinner")
    .ajaxStart -> $(this).fadeIn()
    .ajaxStop -> $(this).fadeOut()
```

And have included the following tag in my main.gsp:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.coffee"/>
```

However, the source I get in the Chrome Browser Developer tools is the following:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.2
(function() {
  console.log("This is my manifest");

  $(function() {
    return $("#spinner").ajaxStart(function() {
      return $(this).fadeIn();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
      return $(this).fadeOut();
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

source, what you see, is actually coffee script "translated" into pure JS. From main page of Coffescript 
"CoffeeScript is a little language that compiles into JavaScript."
(http://coffeescript.org)

Comment: I am aware of that. I want to see the original coffeescript source in the browser debug . Not the translated js